# How to read and parse from multiple files?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have 3 text files that I need to read each content, then grab the relevant fields, and then finally output these fields all together to a new text file. All fields per file should be output as one line (no newline).

My problem is with the final output step.

This is the get content part:

```psh
$raw = Get-Content "C:\folderpath\*.*"
$raw =$raw | Select-String -Pattern "string1", "string2", "string3"
$raw
```

I am getting the following result (all files parsed strings stacked one after the other):

```
PS C:\> $raw = Get-Content "C:\ProgramData\CyberTech\Content\audio1\2015-06-02\1\*.*"
PS C:\> $raw =$raw | Select-String -Pattern "Channel=", "StartTime=", "StopTime=", "Duration=", "FileName=" 
PS C:\> $raw

string1=1
string2=8
string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
string1=1
string2=8
string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
string1=1
string2=8
string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
```

My questions would be: how can I output these results like below example (each of the 3 files strings in on the same line)?

```
String1 String2 String3
String1 String2 String3
String1 String2 String3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is your `$raw` output:

```
string1=1
string2=8
string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
string1=1
string2=8
string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
string1=1
string2=8
string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
```

and you want this as the result:

```
string1=1 string2=8 string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
string1=1 string2=8 string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
string1=1 string2=8 string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
```

you could do something like this:

```psh
$raw = Get-Content "C:\folderpath\*.*"
$raw = $raw | Select-String -Pattern "string1", "string2", "string3"

($raw | Out-String) -replace "`r`n(string[23])", ' $1'
```

The capturing group should match all your field names except the first one, so if you have names that are less alike than `string2` and `string3` you'd use an alternation instead:

```psh
($raw | Out-String) -replace "`r`n(string2|string3)", ' $1'
```

Comment: thanks Ansgar however i am not getting change when adding the code provided 
($raw | Out-String) -replace "`r`n(string[23])", ' $1'

Comment: @rotemshein The code works just fine with the sample data from your question. Please provide evidence.

Comment: you are right its working just fine !! i had a syntax error   


$raw = Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\testfolder\*.*"
$raw = $raw | Select-String -Pattern "string1", "string2", "string3"

($raw | Out-String) -replace "`r`n(string[23])", ' $1'

string1=1 string2=8 string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
string1=1 string2=8 string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
string1=1 string2=8 string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
string1=1 string2=8 string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11
string1=1 string2=8 string3=2015-06-02 23:58:11

Comment: Hi Ansgar, code works great !! my last question would be if instead of "string1,string2,string3" i have different field names like "first" last" "email" can i modify the code provided ?  "`r`n(string[23])", ' ,$1'         thanks again !!

Comment: Use an alternation, but leave out the first field name: "\`r\`n(last|email|...)"